# Image picker that returnes multiple images

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity

I am programming a gallery app which i also want to use as an image picker. Therefore i added following lines to the AndroidManifest.xml which worked.

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Now, when i want to add a photo for example in WhatsApp in a chat, my app shows up as image picker after a long click on the image symbol. If i click on one of my photos it works and adds the clicked photo to the chat. I call this function for this:

```
 fun onPickMedia(action: MediaPickAction) {
        val result = Intent();
        val pickedDir = File(action.mediaPath)
        result.data = pickedDir.toUri();
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
        finish();
    }
```

But when i select more than one photo and then call following function no photos are added and no helpfull errormessage shows up

```
 fun onPickSelectedMedia(state: AppState) {
        val selectedItems = state.selectedMediaItems
        val sharedUris = arrayListOf<Uri>()
        selectedItems.forEach {
            val file = File(state.mediaPath, it.name)
            sharedUris.add(file.toUri())
        }
        Intent().apply {
//          action = Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE
//          type = MediaUtils.MIME_TYPE_IMAGE
//          putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
//          putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, sharedUris)
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, sharedUris)
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, this)
            finish();
        }
    }
```

What do i do wrong?

Comment: If your app would use ACTION_GET_CONTENT to select multiple images from gallery then how would the code in onActivityResult look like to get all the uries? If you have that code then you know what you do wrong.

Comment: Further i have never seen ACTION_GET_CONTENT in this way in an intent filter. Quite interesting. Wil try later.